# How to setup zend 2 routing to expect certain get variables to be passed?

Tags: php, zend-framework2, url-routing

My app is expected to handle a url sent from a 3rd party app with some variables ie: 'www.example.com/user/login?IDUsuario=500'. I configured my route this way:

```
'usuario' => array(
            'type' => 'segment',
            'options' => array(
                'route' => '/usuario[/:login][?:IDUsuario]',
                'constraints' => array(
                    'login' => '[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_-]*',
                    'IDUsuario' => '[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_-]*'
                ),
                'defaults' => array(
                    'controller' => 'Administrativo\Controller\Usuario',
                    'action' => 'index'
                )
            ),
        ),
```

Now, the problem is that my app is not 'seeing' the variables passed through the URL. When I try go get the params using:
    $this->getEvent()->getRouteMatch()->getParams();
I just get a string like:
        array(3) { ["controller"]=> string(33) "Administrativo\Controller    \Usuario" ["action"]=> string(5) "index" ["login"]=> string(5) "login" }

It is not recognizing the variable IDUsuario. How can I get around this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to remove `[?:IDUsuario]` and its corresponding constraint from your route. ZF2 doesn't really handle query parameters in routes. It used to, but it's since been [deprecated](http://framework.zend.com/manual/current/en/modules/zend.mvc.routing.html#zend-mvc-router-http-query-deprecated).

Instead, in your controller you just need to call `$this->params()->fromQuery()` which will return an array of all the query parameters appended onto the URL.